# Crystal - copying a Class

Tags: class, copy, crystal-lang

Is it possible to copy / duplicate a class without going through the initialize method and without creating an empty class and copying the values one by one ?

Ex :

```
class Hello
  def initialize
    puts "hello !"
  end
end

var1 = Hello.new  #=> hello!
var2 = copy(var1) #=>
```

`copy` being a method that will do the class duplication / copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you dont want to copy a class but an object. The method for this ist `dup`.

```
var2 = var1.dup
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use [`dup`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Object.html#dup-instance-method) method:

```
class Hello
  def initialize
    puts "hello !"
  end
end

var1 = Hello.new # hello !
var2 = var1.dup

pp var1 # => #<Hello:0x104134ff0>
pp var2 # => #<Hello:0x104134fe0>
```